# Kotlin Multiplatform: How to call getOriginalKotlinClass from swift?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

How to get Kotlin Class from swift code? I need it for dependency inection. In documentation it says that there's a method getOriginalKotlinClass, but where can I get it?

For example I have an object that is available in swift from Kotlin library `JsonCacheClient`, how do I get its kotlin class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a method in Kotlin, which calls `getOriginalKotlinClass`, expose it and call this method from Swift.

See [this comment](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/2988#issuecomment-591506872) for more info